# Increase Range dimensions

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

i have a named range that refers to range `D3:I23` and this range is well-defined for some automation purposes.

Recently i had an update that required me to redefine this range as `F3:I23` and exclude, initially, columns `D` & `E`.  But further in the various logic coding, i need to include `E` for evaluation (turning dynamic data to static data).

Was thinking of using `Resize` but didnt seem right.  Also thought `Offset` but that moves the whole range forward or backwards.  I basically need to resize the range back 1 column while retaining the original defined range

In essence i need the named range to be defined as `F3:I23` but during this one code segment i need the range to be evaluated to `E3:I23`.

Any thoughts, or combination of Range properties to use in VBA?  At the point that i am passing the reference, it is being stored in a `Range` object, so any chained set of properties is fair game.

Please try to apply the `KISS` policy when answering.  Doesnt need to be an overly complex formula, as i am not guaranteed to be the one supporting the end result.

Comment: The Resize and Offset methods are often used together for this purpose. These methods give you a Range object that you can use inline, or you can declare a new variable for the resized/offset range.

Comment: Troller downvote, 1/8/2014, over 1 yr after this question posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rachel indicated... this should do the trick assumes your named range is defined as namedRange:

```
Set neededRange = namedRange.Resize(namedRange.Rows.Count, _
              namedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Offset(0, -1)
```

Resize to increase the columns included by 1, then offset the entire range by -1 column to get your `neededRange`.